# How to get just base url like www.example.com in python split

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, split

In a loaded webpage address I want only base url and remove the tails. How can I get it please help me.

Comment: You should add the [python] tag for better visibility.

Answer (score 2):

check out the `urllib.parse` module:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

you can use the `urlparse` or `urlsplit` methods to break up a url into components...

suppose you have the following url: `http://example.com/foo?bar=1#baz`

It is make up several components: a protocol scheme, network location, path, parameters, query string, and fragment.

for example:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

>>> url = 'http://example.com/foo?bar=1#baz'
>>> o = urlparse(url)
>>> o
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='example.com', path='/foo', params='', query='bar=1', fragment='baz')
>>> o.netloc
'example.com'
```